# IBM Worklight - closing application not clearing my login

Tags: sencha-touch-2, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I am new to worklight & sencha touch. We are developing an app using sencha touch 2.

How do I handle gracious exit of my application kill or accidental close? I want to logout automatically and change status of my login in DB so that I can still login again with same credentials.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not related to the framework you've chosen to develop your application with (Sencha Touch 2). Rather, it is about the authentication flow in your application's logic.

You do not mention in the question how and what you have implemented thus far... This is critical information.

Basically, what you will want to do is to protect your application with a security test.
Without knowing anything about your project, this is the best advise I find myself able to provide you.

I suggest that you will read the following training modules section and understand how Worklight's Authentication framework works.
This will allow you to develop your application with authentication in mind, and thus create the flow you require - that is, display a login form on application launch.

Related:

- [Authentication and security](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#security)
- [Understanding predefined Worklight authentication realms and security tests](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding_predefined_worklight_authentication_realms_and_security_tests11?lang=en)

---